# How to use DataGridView checkbox in Combobox's Select Change event?

Tags: vb.net

- I want to create a mobile phone project in VB.net 2019. Where the model of the mobile phone in the Combobox came from the database. I have attached a datagridview where the IMEI number of the mobile phone is displayed. An attached checkbox in Datagridview. The problem is that when I go to change the model number of the mobile phone in the change event of Combobox, a new checkbox is added to every change in Datagridview.
- I created a searchbox to easily find IEMI numbers in a textbox. When I search the IEMI number in the search box in the datagridview and check in the datagridview checkbox and search for the next number, the previous one is unchecked

I am praying for the help of the experienced.

```
Sub display_data()     
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select Product_Name, IMEI_No,qty from tbl_Stock where Company_Name=@d1 and Product_Name =@d2", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_cmp.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_pro.Text
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
   con.Close()
    Dim chakbox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    chakbox.Width = 60
    chakbox.Name = "checkbox"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, chakbox)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_pro.SelectedIndexChanged
 
    con.Open()
    Dim strsql As New SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_pro where Product_name=@d1", con)
    strsql.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_pro.Text
    Dim myreader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = strsql.ExecuteReader
    While myreader.Read
        txt_sal_rt.Text = myreader.GetDecimal("sale_rate")
        txt_pro_cod.Text = myreader.GetString("product_code")
        txt_pur_rt.Text = myreader.GetDecimal("Purchase_rate")
    End While
    con.Close()

    display_data()
End Sub

Private Sub txt_serch_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txt_serch.KeyUp
    DataGridView1.DataSource = searech()
End Sub

Private Function searech() As DataTable
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select Product_Name, IME_No,qty from tbl_Stock where Company_Name=@d1 and IME_NO Like '%' +@d2 + '%'", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_cmp.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_serch.Text

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish. Adding some images may be helpful.

Comment: This line DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, chakbox) adds a new column every time it's executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a bool in your query, throw that "add a checkbox to the grid" code away

```
Sub display_data()     
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select CAST(0 as BIT) as checkbox, Product_Name, IMEI_No,qty from tbl_Stock where Company_Name=@d1 and Product_Name =@d2", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_cmp.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmb_pro.Text
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
   con.Close()

End Sub
```